# In WindowsPhone8, how to make first list box item to be always selected and selected item color to be changed?

Tags: windows, windows-phone-8

I am using a list box, in that there are 6 items. i want first item should always be selected and on tapping other items selected changed. Also selected item to be changed.

Answer (score 0):

For the first item to always be selected, you can select it in your code in the "OnNavigatedTo" method of your .xaml.cs file.

For the color of selecting items to change, you can create a template resource, [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/system.windows.controls.listbox%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) links explains it